# c# desserializar xml dentro de una clase

Tags: c#, xml

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta.
Tengo una clase Origen, que tiene la siguiente estructura

```
    public class Origen
{
    public int IdOrigen { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public decimal Peso { get; set; }
    public bool Verdadero { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

Lleno esta clase con datos de la siguiente manera

```
            #region Llena la clase con datos
        Origen origen = new Origen();
        origen.IdOrigen = 1;
        origen.Nombre = "Nombre1";
        origen.Peso = 234;
        origen.Verdadero = true;
        origen.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
        #endregion
```

Luego la serializo con la siguiente funcion

```
        private static string SerializarToXml(Object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(strWriter, obj);
            string resultXml = strWriter.ToString();
            strWriter.Close();
            return resultXml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

esto me genera un string xml sin problemas

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

-<Origen xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<IdOrigen>1</IdOrigen>

<Nombre>Nombre1</Nombre>

<Peso>234</Peso>

<Verdadero>true</Verdadero>

<Fecha>2017-11-17T17:40:52.9402905-03:00</Fecha>

</Origen>
```

pues bien.. para poder rescatar estos datos utilizo el siguiente codigo

```
        XmlDocument xmlDatoRescatado = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDatoRescatado.LoadXml(xmlDatos);
        XmlNode nodoMain = xmlDatoRescatado.SelectSingleNode("Origen");
        int IdOrigen = Convert.ToInt32(nodoMain.SelectSingleNode("IdOrigen").LastChild.Value);
        string nombre = nodoMain.SelectSingleNode("Nombre").LastChild.Value;
        decimal peso = Convert.ToDecimal(nodoMain.SelectSingleNode("Peso").LastChild.Value);
        bool Verdadero = Convert.ToBoolean(nodoMain.SelectSingleNode("Verdadero").LastChild.Value);
        DateTime Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(nodoMain.SelectSingleNode("Fecha").LastChild.Value);
```

pero este metodo es poco efectivo para mi, porque la clase real que serializo tiene muchas definiciones, entonces queria saber, si es que existe una forma de desserializar el xml, pasandole el molde de la clase que quiero que contenga esos datos..  en este caso una copia de la clase Origen.

Es esto posible? o definitivamente el unico metodo es el que estoy usando hasta el momento?
Saludos y gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: [Método XmlSerializer.Deserialize (XmlReader)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo correcto es que deserializar el xml a la clase, como se explica aqui

[Cómo: Deserializar un objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object)

seria algo como esto

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Origen));  

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("ruta archivo xml", FileMode.Open);  

Origen origen = (Origen)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
```

Comment: Como siempre, excelente respuesta. finalmente sustitui el filestream por un strinreader y se lo pase a la funcion deserializer. Gracias leandro